# Best way to have a lookup table in an iphone app without loading it to memory

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data, nsdictionary

I have an iphone app with a large(6-7MB) keyvalue file that I would like to avoid loading into memory. It is used very rarely, and chewing up that amount of RAM seems unnecessary.

Right now it is a flat text file with lines in the format

```
KEY VALUE
```

but I am happy to store it however works best.

What is the best approach for this?  SQLite is an option, but that seems quite a heavyweight solution.  I'm told that coredata is a good interface to SQLite, but it seems to me that this would still involve loading the entire file to memory as an nsdictaionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **SQLite is not a "heavyweight" solution**. Its memory requirements are quite low, and its performance is good. If you use SQLite, you'll probably want a wrapper like FMDB or PLDatabase to make it easier to use in Objective-C.

Next, **Core Data is not a wrapper for SQLite**. It *uses* SQLite internally, but that's an implementation detail that is not exposed in the Core Data API. Core Data would work in this situation, but if you think of it in SQL-style terms then I guarantee that you'll screw it up.

If you're only using the table rarely, the simplest approach would be to save it as JSON or as a property list and just read the whole thing on demand. As long as you're careful to unload it when you're done and you're not already pushing memory limits, I wouldn't worry about it. If you might get to where you need it more often, consider either SQLite or Core Data-- either will allow you to look up the values you need without loading the whole thing into memory.

Answer (score 1):

How would you search for a key witout loading all keys into memory?

You could implement your own indexing scheme, or just use SQLite (whose code is likely to be already in memory because of some other app or service).

Answer (score 0):

Six or seven MB isn't big.  Thus you could just load it into a dictionary and then when you are through ensure that it is deleted/unlinked.  Alternately you could just write your own query and read the file lines yourself scanning for the key.  But 6-7 MB isn't big.

If you have control of the file content, just use the existing Apple frameworks to write it as a `plist` and then to read in the `plist` as a dictionary and do your queries.